# CDF of time spent to complete two Jobs with time that follows a Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics

Suppose that we have a single core CPU that start to compute two jobs at time t=0.

Let T be the time spent by this CPU in order to complete these two jobs, what will be the CDF of T in this two cases:

1) the two jobs have the same parameter alpha

2) the first job has parameter alpha and the second 2*alpha

Consider that the time spent by each one of the two jobs follows a Poisson distribution.

The CPU can't do multithreading computation.

Comment: How many cores does the CPU have?  If the jobs can be done in parallel, the answer is different than if they have to be done sequentially.

Comment: It has only one CPU

Comment: And even with one core, there is multithreading to consider.

Comment: Yeah you are right, sorry. But in this case let us consider this CPU unable to do any form of multithreading computation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the jobs have to be run sequentially and the times for each are independent, the sum of two independent Poisson random variables with parameters $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ is Poisson with parameter $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$.

Comment: Ok, thank's for the answer, Mr. Israel!